# how to get value from two table in mysql with from one table distinct and from other table multiple value?

Tags: java, mysql

i have two table in database like:
table_one with fields like: class , day_of_week and id(pk);
table_two with fields like:  id(fk) , subjects

and what i tried is:

select distinct day_of_week ,subjects from table_one as tbl_one ,table_two as tbl_two where tbl_one.id =tbl_two.id and class_name='One'[?];

and my result comes out for my report like:
 
**day of week: **     **       subjects** 
Sunday                             A 
Sunday                             B 
Monday                             A 
Monday                             B

but it should come like this: 
**day of week**                       **subjects** 
Sunday                             A 
                                   B 
Monday                             A 
 
                                   B

Comment: Show us the data you have in the tables. And format the code, please.

Comment: @Thrash Bean sir, i have somewhat edited and formatted my question , i am new so my stuff would be fresher level but i'd appreciate your help , in my problem , what solution i want is , there is two table as mentioned above and both are linked by pk id and i want to get value from both table by referencing id but for single day of week there will be several subjects to study so day of week should not be replicate thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want days of week, and want each of them associated with multiple subjects. You'll have to use Java code for this. SQL can't magically do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sir? WOW, thank you.

I'm not sure I understand very well what you pretend, but as I see your result is correct. Your edited code is impossible since you could get

```
Sunday, A, B
Monday, A, B
```

but not

```
Sunday, A
      , B
```

What you need is agregate function. InMySQL this is [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). In your case the query may look like this:

```
SELECT day_of_week, GROUP_CONCAT(subjects) AS subjects 
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP_BY subjects
```

Also take a look at [User defined functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-udf.html).

I hope I understood your question and this answer helps you. If not, please correct me and ask again.